# real meaning of nofollow links

Tags: seo

i'm getting confused what are realy nofollow attributes do.
I do believe that they tell search engine spiders to do not follow the target.
But my question is: do nofollow links alter the Pagerank?

Thanks

Comment: SEOoverflow? these type of q's belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Either BLAMEoverflow isn't here, just had a question at the time i didn't even realized that webmasters.stackexchange.com exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**nofollow** is poorly named. I'll try and give another explanation:

All the links on a web page acquire *link juice* that they can pass on to the pages they link to.

The amount of juice available to a page is based on the *link juice* it receives from other pages that link it. This all relates to the **PageRank** algorithm.

How the juice is distributed to the links is outside the question, and a Google secret. But each link gets a share.

**nofollow** in a link says don't pass on my share of *link juice*.

What is believed is that this *link juice* is just leaked out so using nofollow cannot be used to retain ranking. Just to deny the recipient of any boost in their ranking.

A good use for **nofollow** is when external users can add their own links in your website. This can protect you from people spamming you to pass on juice to their own websites.

Comment: By "leaked out", Do you mean that normal links without the tag will actually make our page rank lower because *juice* is leaked out?

Comment: No, links with nofollow just throw away the PageRank they could have passed on. So nofollow links can make your page rank lower.

Comment: By that, doesn't that mean that the best way to rank higher is to have no links (be it nofollow or normal) at all?

Comment: No, A page does not lose PageRank in its links. It shares what it has. Say a page has PR5. If it has 5 links then each get PR1 passed to them. The original page is still PR5. If 1 is nofollow then the other 4 still get PR1 and the nofollow gets nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I once remembered that having too many links actually *reduces* that page's PageRank...

Comment: If outgoing links do affect a URLs performance then it would be outside the scope of the PageRank algorithm and more to do with the 100s of other factors Google takes into account.

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is a simplified pipe google uses to serve your pages

- discovery
- crawling
- indexing
- ranking

discovery is basically the step to discovery new urls, common sources are

- links it finds on other pages
- sitemap.xml

adding a nofollow to a link on your page and google disocovers that links basically pushes the link into the google discovery queue, but with the flag "nofollow = do not crawl that site (based on this discovery), do not index this url (based on this discovery), do not rank this url (based on this discovery)"

so basically you have de-valued that specific link. the link does not count as a vote for that other page.

said that:
it does not help you to save "pagerank" - the concept of pagerank is just thoughtcancer - the "link juice" does not stay on your page, it just get flushed into nirvana. congrats. it's like voting with a note not to count that vote.

there are only 2 use cases when a nofollow links makes sense

- if you can't (user generated content without editorial quality assurance)
- or if you won't (a link to a site you want to point out is sh*t)

vote for another page.

p.s.: this is the site for not programming related SEO questions https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the link http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

nofollow is indeed badly named. What it does is prevent the passing of PageRank and anchor text benefit to the receiving link. However, nofollow links can still be beneficial. Trust and authority can still be passed on, so a link from Wikipedia is still very valuable.

Answer (score -1):

Nofollow attribute means not to pass the PR with link..Nofollow links does not alter Page rank..but they can help in driving traffic towards to your site.. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you have links on your pages that link to external web sites, you can add `nofollow` so that your site does not "spill" page rank to the external pages that you link to (which they would if you don't add `nofollow`).

Comment: No. Google states clearly one should not use nofollow to avoid pagerank "spilling".

Comment: @bugspy.net, ok, why don't you downvote all the other answers too then?

Comment: see http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/ for an explanation by matt cutts, that nofollow does not stop "spilling"